# I am trying to get data from a row in a table items in which a column is 'itemName' in itemName there a 10 values

Tags: java, if-statement, jdbc, while-loop, resultset

now user come to my program and enter the name of any value,then i want to show the value.

```
System.out.println("enter name of item you want to order");
String userOrder = br.readLine();

Connection con = ConnectionToDB.connection();
String itemName= "select itemName from items";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(itemName);

while(rs.next())
{
    if (rs.getString("itemName").equals(userOrder))
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("itemName"));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("you order wrong item that not present");
    }
}
```

when user enter 1st value that present in table that execute well and show the first values but when user input any other value that present in database but `rs.next()` is not working and else part executed. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont simply use:
`"select itemName from items WHERE itemName = " + userOrder`

This way you dont need iterate the result set you just:

```
if (rs.next()){
 //Found
}
else {
 //Not Found
}
```